# How to get started in python

Tags: python, windows

I am just getting started with Python and either can't seem to set up my working directory or am improperly read attempting to print something.

I am trying to print 'Hello World'

### Heading

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noahs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-41ca3e3a1438>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Desktop/Python/filename.py', wdir='D:/Desktop/Python')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 11, in execfile
    stream = tokenize.open(file)  # @UndefinedVariable
  File "C:\Users\noahs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/Desktop/Python/filename.py'
```

I am not sure what these extra files are or why I can not get Python to print this

Comment: Uninstall Python and then re-install python for everyone ( every user) Then try to print 'Hello World'.

Comment: Per the error, it seems to be that the system simply can't read "D:/Desktop/Python/filename.py".  Is that your file or a part of the Python install?  Given that it's on the Desktop, at the root level of a dir named Python, I'm guessing that that's your file.  If so, then I'm thinking that this has nothing to do with your Python installation but rather just the permissions on that one file. - I'd suggest that you try opening up the perms on that one file

Comment: Those other files are just part of IPython and PyCharm.  You're trying to run this from PyCharm, right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, btw.  You're going to have better luck getting answers here if you show us more of what you're doing.  Why don't you show us the code you're trying to run, and tell us more about how you're executing it.

Comment: I was only trying to set up python. I am currently an R user but am trying to get into using python so I dont have any code I am currently using in python

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Python Console/IDE in Administrator's mode. That should solve it.

This is most likely happening because you installed Python for a single user instead of all users on your computer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall python again. And when installing make sure to check the box containing Add to path python {version}. And you will be fine. Then try again!